# Django rest update object from other model

Tags: python, django, rest

I am using Django 1.7 with [REST framework,](http://www.django-rest-framework.org). I want to update the cart instance and then create new instance of order.

```
#models.py

class Cart(models.Model):
  to_be_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  ...

class Order(models.Model):
  ...

#views.py
class OrderBuyList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = OrderBuySerializer

def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = request.data
    # First mark cart instance to be deleted and then create an order instance
    # Request can come from cart.
    cart = Cart.objects.filter(id=data['id'],user_id=data['user_id'])
    if cart:
        cart[0].to_be_deleted = True
        cart[0].save()
    return generics.ListCreateAPIView.create(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I feel this is not a best way to write this logic. Because following situation can occur, cart is updated and order instance is not created. Then I don't know how to know which cart was `not` converted to order.
Is there any better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually create the order and update the cart after that, something like this:

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = request.data
    cart = Cart.objects.get(id=data['id'],user_id=data['user_id'])
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    order = Order.objects.create(**serializer.validated_data)
    cart.to_be_deleted = True
    cart.save()
    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```